# Rel instead of Set in a concrete category

Tags: category-theory, terminology

*Concrete category* is a pair $( \mathcal{C}; U)$ where $\mathcal{C}$
is a category and $U$ is a faithful functor $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow
\mathbf{Set}$.

But how to name a a pair $( \mathcal{C}; U)$ where $\mathcal{C}$
is a category and $U$ is a faithful functor $\mathcal{C} \rightarrow
\mathbf{Rel}$? Is there a standard name for this? If not, let us invent a new term.

Comment: Exercise: a category is concrete relative to $\mathbf{Set}$ if and only if it is concrete relative to $\mathbf{Rel}$.

Comment: @ZhenLin: What?! Why? It seems not true

Comment: It is true. It is enough to show that $\mathbf{Set}$ is concrete relative to $\mathbf{Rel}$ (easy) and that $\mathbf{Rel}$ is concrete relative to $\mathbf{Set}$ (think creatively).

Comment: @ZhenLin: Do you mean "concretizable" relative ... when you say "concrete relative..."? If so, I've misunderstood you. My question is unrelated with concretizability. I just ask about terminology for $( \mathcal{C}; U)$

Comment: A concrete category over Set is called a construct. There does not seem to be a special name for concrete categories over Rel